# Using inline cmdline expressions in windows

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, shell

I wondered if I could use inline cmd expression like in the example
``` :args ``find -iname *.py`` ```

So, I wanted to either use WSL expressions(same as above) or powershell (`Get-ChildItem C:\temp | Select-Object -Property Name`) .

I tried `set shell=wsl.exe` as well as with powershell and it returned errors. Like `Shell returned 127 or 4000 or ...` .
I use neovim.

Is it possible? Any workaround?

OK, the problem is wider.
Notice I run in windows natively(possible a mistake ).

When I try `set shell=wsl.exe` and afterwards I try for example
`<c-r>=system('echo a')` .  I get back `/bin/bash: /s: No such file or directory`.

UPDATE

`r! powershell -Command "Write-Host x"` works, but not when used inside :args..
``` :args ``powershell -Command "Write-Host x"`` ```  doesn't.

Comment: I run neovim natively in windows. I have windows subsystem for linux installed , and I can use it to run linux commands (for example in terminal).

Comment: Now I see what you mean. I've never heard of using `wsl.exe` like that. If you want to run bash commands from Windows native vim then install Cygwin or equivalent.

Comment: I worked quite hard to have my plugins comptabile with windows. I have use than 60 plugins. FZF , vim-netranger and others  were problematic, but I got over it.. The consideration was performance.

Comment: I use gvim with Cygwin and it works pretty well. Sure it's not as fast as WSL but I haven't had any issues. But anyways...maybe someone knows how to rig up WSL the way you describe. Just cuz I've never heard of it doesn't mean it can't be done. :)

Comment: `I get back /bin/bash: /s` You have to set up properly all shell-related options, especially shellcmdflag. Vim can't guess everything right. Read through all help topics starting with backtick-shell... There are quite a few of them.

Comment: Regarding your update I just tried the kind of thing I had in my ill-conceived answer: `:exe "args " . system('powershell -Command "Write-Host x"')` and it actually set the argslist to "x".

Comment: you are right. You may post this as an answer. Although, I prefer also WSL to work.. but maybe solvable similarly.

Comment: Okay. Before I do so did you try it with a command that returns multiple files? I'm wondering if you'll actually need the `substitute()` after all!

Comment: Does `:help 'shellcmdflag'` help you here? (I'm in Vim, not NeoVim, and on Linux, but the help docs talk about powershell in particular...)

Comment: Soon. I feel like there is a better solution. `:help shellcmdflag` . It should be `-Command` . But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Googled this: https://robindouglas.uk/powershell/vim/2018/04/05/PowerShell-with-Vim.html  It has all the vim `shell*` settings ... try that.

Comment: `:help {arglist}` says "On Unix and a few other systems you can also use backticks", but it doesn't really go much into details of how "Unix" is defined here... Maybe it's not really possible on native Windows build?

Comment: Following @B Layer suggestion, I tried to run powershell commands with `!` and it didn't seem to work. Before rest was better, Mostly, when I try args with tick and ps commands, I get  `E484: Can't open file C:\Users\ekarni\AppData\Local\Temp\nvimb5LrJk\3
E479: No match`

Comment: Maybe try `:set noshelltemp`...I've seen that used to solve certain problems with shell commands and temp files.

Comment: no effect. xxxxx

Comment: see `:help shell-powershell` . Doesn't resolve it though.